# Running Timers in the Background c# Console

Tags: c#, timer

Wondering if there's a way to have a timer running in the background of a project that can be accessed if the user inputs a certain thing. At the moment this doesn't work

```
Timer t = new Timer(Program.TimerCallback, null, 0, 1000);
if (Console.ReadLine() == "i")
{
    TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Program.seconds);
    string str = time.ToString(@"mm\:ss");
    Console.WriteLine("Time :" + str);
}
public static void TimerCallback(object o)
{
    seconds +=1;
}
```

I used to have to code above within the Callback but then I couldn't do anything while it was running the timer. Thanks for any help

Comment: " I couldn't do anything while it was running the timer." what exactly did you try to do? because this timer is made for shooting once and it is running in the background. At least if you start it. I don't see the code where you actually enable the timer

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Output some kind of "running for mm:ss time" output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you don't actually need a timer:

```
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now; // Just have a reference time
if (Console.ReadLine() == "i")
{
    TimeSpan time = DateTime.Now - startTime; // Compute difference between "now" and "then"
    string str = time.ToString(@"mm\:ss");
    Console.WriteLine("Time :" + str);
}
```

should do the trick.

Subtracting two DateTimes like this gives you a TimeSpan: [DateTime.Subtraction Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.op_subtraction?view=netcore-3.1)

If you need better precision, you can make use of the [StopWatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netcore-3.1) class, which also has a little more convenient API:

```
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();
if (Console.ReadLine() == "i")
{
    TimeSpan time = stopWatch.Elapsed;
    string str = time.ToString(@"mm\:ss");
    Console.WriteLine("Time :" + str);
}
```

**BUT** do not think you can do (micro-)benchmarks with this. If you intend to do so, consider [Benchmark.NET](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/) (not affiliated).